# CSS moving list text to other side

Tags: html, css

Im a big noob when it comes to HTML and CSS. So I have this HTML:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-areas: "up" "mid" "bot";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin: auto;
}

ul .left {}

ul .right {}

header {
  grid-area: up;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <ul class="left">
        <li>IM</li>
        <li>LEFT</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right">
        <li>I</li>
        <li>WANNA</li>
        <li>BE</li>
        <li>RIGHT</li>
      </ul>
    </header>
</body>
```

All I need is for the ul with class="right" to move to the right of the screen. so the left would populate on the left side and right would populate on the opposite side, like this:
| LEFT ---------------- RIGHT  |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` to have 2 column layout.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-areas: "up" "mid" "bot";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: auto;
}

ul .left {}

ul.right {
  text-align: right;
  /* if you want the content right */
}

ul .right {}

header {
  grid-area: up;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="left">
    <li>IM</li>
    <li>LEFT</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
    <li>I</li>
    <li>WANNA</li>
    <li>BE</li>
    <li>RIGHT</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do float: left and float: right